# Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: magento-connect, downloader

I am trying to install an extension in my magento store through Magento Connect but I am facing the below issue. I checked my php info and curl is enabled.
The extension I a installing is http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/TBT_Enhancedgrid

Error is
[image]

If anybody has the solution for this please help me to fix this ..

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

using above code first find **CURL** check protocol listed there check https is available or not [image]

if not listed then CURL was not built with SSL support and you cannot use https.

I suggest one simple solution to download extension using [link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php)

Comment: Thanks , I tried the link and I was able to get the complete package.